# python yield function with callback args

Tags: python, scrapy

This is the first time I ask question here. If something I got wrong, please forgive me.
And I am a newer in python for one month, I try to use the scrapy to learn something more about spider.

question is here:

```
    def get_chapterurl(self, response):
       item = DingdianItem()
       item['name'] = str(response.meta['name']).replace('\xa0', '')
       yield item
       yield Request(url=response.url, callback=self.get_chapter, meta={'name':name_id})


    def get_chapter(self, response):
       urls = re.findall(r'<td class="L"><a href="(.*?)">(.*?)</a></td>', response.text)
```

As you can see, I yield item and Requests at the same time, but the get_chapter function did not run the first line(I take a break point there), so where was I wrong? 
Sorry for disturbing you.
I have google for a time, but get noting...

Comment: You are not yielding those two at the same time.  Those are two different statement.

Comment: So why the get_chapter did not run? How should I change?[link](https://github.com/ReZeroS/dingdian)

Comment: I am afraid i do not know what the purpose of either of these functions is.  You did not explain it or provide any reference as to its intended purpose.

Comment: Maybe I found the real question, I ask this question in another way, parse1(self, responseSame) has a yield Request(responseSame.url,parse2):    Request(response.url, call_back=parse2), the call_back won't run when it receive the same response from parse1, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request gets filtered out.

Scrapy has in-built request filter that prevents you from downloading the same page twice (intended feature).

Lets say you are on http://example.com; this request you yield:

```
yield Request(url=response.url, callback=self.get_chapter, meta={'name':name_id})
```

tries to download http://example.com again. And if you look at the crawling log it should say something along the lines of "ignoring duplicate url http://example.com".
You can always ignore this feature by setting `dont_filter=True` parameter in your `Request` object, as so:

```
yield Request(url=response.url, callback=self.get_chapter, meta={'name':name_id},
              dont_filter=True)
```

However! I'm having trouble understanding the intention of your code but it seems that you don't really want to download the same url twice.
You don't have to schedule a new request either, you can just call your callback with the request you already have:

```
response = response.replace(meta={'name': name_id})  # update meta
# why crawl it again, if we can just call the callback directly!
# for python2
for result in self.get_chapter(response):  
    yield result
# or if you are running python3:
yield from self.get_chapter(response):
```